# Failed to get success response in “application/json” using Name Credential

Tags: apex, http, httpresponse

HttpResponse in “text/html” instead in “application/json” if using Name Credential

**Step1** : Name Credential
[image]

**Step 2**: Authentication & Authorization Code

[image]

**RESPONSE**
[image]

```
header>>>>>: Server value>>>>>: myclient Authority Server

header>>>>>: Connection value>>>>>: keep-alive

header>>>>>: Content-Length value>>>>>: 475

header>>>>>: Date value>>>>>: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 02:36:00 GMT

header>>>>>: Content-Type value>>>>>: application/json
```

**Step 3**: After Authentication Calling further API with access token using **name credential**

[image]

**ERROR RESPONSE**: response in text/html instead in **application/json**
[image]

```
header>>>>>: Server value>>>>>: awselb/2.0

header>>>>>: Connection value>>>>>: close

header>>>>>: Content-Length value>>>>>: 138

header>>>>>: Date value>>>>>: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 02:36:00 GMT

***header>>>>>: Content-Type value>>>>>: text/html***
```

**Step 4**: Added remote site settings
[image]

**Step 5**: Instead Name Credentials using complete/direct API URL and getting SUCCESS response

[image]

In the above case using remote site setting I am getting SUCCESS response but we don't want to use remote site settings we would love to stick with the same procedure as authentication using name credentials which is working fine.

Comment: I think by using your named cred for the second call you’re duplicating the authentication (which is present in the named creds) already. I would use the straight url.